How to prevent Google style clang formatter from ordering 'using typename' alphabetically?
My project is using a clang-format based on 'Google Style' and I would like to disable the feature that sorts using typename ... alphabetically when several are added back to back  .  Is there any way to do this?
Thank you.

Why are you not reading the clang-format documentation for this?

For this, use
SortUsingDeclarations.
You have three options:

Never (which you want) - Using declarations are never sorted.
Lexicographic - Using declarations are sorted in the order defined as follows: Split the strings by :: and discard any initial empty strings. Sort the lists of names lexicographically, and within those groups, names are in case-insensitive lexicographic order.
LexicographicNumeric - Using declarations are sorted in the order defined as follows: Split the strings by :: and discard any initial empty strings. The last element of each list is a non-namespace name; all others are namespace names. Sort the lists of names lexicographically, where the sort order of individual names is that all non-namespace names come before all namespace names, and within those groups, names are in case-insensitive lexicographic order.

